# Comma separated string split

Tags: r

I'm trying convert this vector string

```
a<-c("1,2,3","344")
```

into this

```
a<-c("1","2","3","344")
```

I'm using the following code:

```
a<-c("1,2,3","344")

b<-strsplit(a, ",")

c<-sapply( b, paste0, collapse=",")
```

But I'm getting back to the original vector:

```
c<-c("1,2,3","344")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Albit

Comment: `do.call(c, sapply(a, strsplit, ","))`

Comment: or: `sapply(unlist(b), paste0, collapse=",")`

Comment: b <- unlist(strsplit(a, ","))

Comment: @EnriquePérezHerrero Just deleted my answer. Saw my solution was identical to yours.

Comment: Great! This worked. Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
a <- c("1,2,3","344")
scan(text = a, sep = ",", what = "")
# [1] "1"   "2"   "3"   "344"
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is identical to the one on my comment:

```
a <- c("1,2,3", "344")
b <- unlist(strsplit(a, ","))
b
[1] "1"   "2"   "3"   "344"
```